# int class なのに int() でキャストしないとエラーになる

Tags: python

https://pyorc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-custom-converters
pyorc というモジュールのカスタムクラス内で

```
class TestConverter(ORCConverter):
    @staticmethod
    def to_orc(obj, timezone):
      print(obj)
      print(type(obj))
      return (obj, 0)
```

```
1646092740
<class 'int'>
2022-03-02 13:21:12,888 [ERROR] Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type (compile in debug mode for details)
```

というデバッグ出力とエラーになります

```
      return (int(obj), 0)
```

とかくとエラーになりません

> [ERROR] Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type (compile in debug mode for details)

これはどういう意味のエラーなんでしょうか

元々 <class 'int'> なのに int(obj) でキャストすると何が変化するんでしょうか

---

再現できるデータを見極めたいんですがなかなか再現しません

エラーが再現するソースコード全体は後述のものになります

他のプログラムがシリアライズ化した marshal ファイルをもう１度よみこんでそのまま 中身を orc writer に流し込むだけなのでデータに依存してるんだと思いますが、データの中身は業務情報が含まれていて公開できません

ただエラーになる直前のログは

```
(1646200394,)
1646200394
<class 'int'>
```

となるのでこの値を書き込んでエラーがでているのは間違い無いんですが
コメントアウトしてる行を追加してこの値のみの１レコードを書き込んだファイルではエラーにならず成功します

```
import datetime
import pyorc
import marshal
from pyorc.converters import ORCConverter

class TestConverter(ORCConverter):
  @staticmethod
  def to_orc(obj, timezone):
    print(obj)
    print(type(obj))
    return (obj, 0)

# with open('test.msl', 'wb') as f:
#   marshal.dump((1646200394,), f)

with open('test.orc', 'wb') as orc_file:
  orc_writer = pyorc.Writer(
    orc_file,
    'struct<time:timestamp>',
    converters={pyorc.TypeKind.TIMESTAMP: TestConverter},
  )
  with open('test.msl', 'rb') as f:
    try:
      while True:
        row = marshal.load(f)
        print(row)
        orc_writer.write(row)
    except EOFError:
      pass
  
  orc_writer.close()
```

Comment: 問題の事象を再現するには情報(ソースコードの記述)が足らないように見えます。完結したソースコードを提示してみてください。[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if not isinstance(obj, int)
    print(obj)
    print(type(obj))
```

といれてみたところ float のデータが混ざっていました
marshal データを作る側で python のデフォルトで datetime 型から timestamp() をよぶと float になっちゃってたみたいです

ここからは想像ですが
pyorc は列単位である程度データが溜まってからファイル出力するので
write をよんでもすぐにかきこまれずに変換時になってもっと前に書き込んだ float を int 出力しようとしてエラーになったみたいです

お騒がせしました